# Cannot understand the 10 year VTI growth chart on Vanguard

Tags: etf, compound-interest, vanguard

The image below shows the performance of [Vanguard Total Stock Market ETF](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/performance/vti) (NYSE Arca: VTI). I cannot understand how $10,000 becomes $34,070 after 10 years with a 10-year return of 12.80%.

Shouldn't it be $10,000 * 1.128 = $11,280 ?

Is some kind of compounding happening here? What's the equation?

[image: VTI performance]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot understand how $10,000 becomes $34,070 after 10 years with a 10-year return of 12.80%.

12.80% is the compound annual growth rate (CAGR). It is 12.80% every year for 10 years.

[image: \sqrt[10]{\frac{34070}{10000}} \approx 1.13]

> Shouldn't it be $10,000 * 1.128 = $11,280 ?

No. It should be [image: 10000(1.128^{10}) \approx 33350]

Comment: Does it mean I need to re-invest the profits back into ETF to make it reach $33k. Or does it mean that the VTI grows 12.8% per year and if I just sit on it for 10 years it will become $33k. I googled "CAGR" and investopedia says "assuming the profits were reinvested at the end of each year of the investment’s lifespan" in this link here https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp

Comment: @user855 By "re-invest the profits", do you mean reinvesting the dividends?

Comment: I have no clue about this. That Investopedia website was using those words. I really just want to know if I buy VTI (say $10k worth) now, what else do I need to do each year so that it becomes $34k in 10 years. Do nothing else? Or do I need to "reinvest" as this article is claiming I need to do?

Comment: @user855 If the performance numbers on Vanguard's website include dividend reinvestment (i.e. "total return"), then you would have had to reinvest all dividends to reach $34,070. If the numbers do not include dividend reinvestment (i.e. "price return"), then you would not have had to reinvest your dividends to reach $34,070.

Comment: @user855 I have no idea whether or not Vanguard's numbers assume dividend reinvestment. You can check with them.

Comment: +1 and a couple comments - For a millisecond I thought "when did we get Latex here?" then I saw the clever image. Nicely done. And yes, funds show "total return", so it would be what a lump sum investor would get if they reinvested dividends every time.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica I found a free and open-source LaTeX equation editor for Windows and Linux: [EqualX](https://equalx.sourceforge.io). It is helpful for visualizing LaTeX equations, and it is able create images of equations in various file formats and sizes. The images in my post were made using an online tool. I found EqualX later.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica Do all fund performance information show "total return"? Is it the standard convention? How are dividend taxes accounted for?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica I also wanted to ask: what could explain the discrepancy between the 12.80% that Vanguard claims, and the 13% (actually 13.04% to 2 decimal places) I calculated?

Comment: @Flux the $'s are updated every trading day but the table is updated once a month. They will only match on one day a month.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep "They will only match on one day a month" But that day should be today or yesterday, and hence the numbers should match. The $34,070 is presumably based on closing prices on Friday afternoon, but the table was updated just yesterday (Saturday)!